# Сортировка объектов в массиве по убыванию используя значение в HashMap содержащееся в объекте!

Tags: java

Есть класс Player он содержит в себе переменные privat String name (никнейм игрока), privat double statistic (общая статистика) и privat HashMap <String, Double> games ( где ключ - название игры, а значение статистика игрока по этой игре).
При регистрации пользователя класс Player добавляется в Linked list.
ВОПРОС!!!
Как мне вывести список(или создать Array list и вывести его) по убыванию по какой то определенной игре, ориентируясь на значение в HashMap (Double)??? Но нужно чтобы на выходе был не только HashMap, а весь объект kласса Player

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private HashMap<String, Double> games;
    private double statistic;

    public Player() {
    }

    public Player(String name, HashMap<String, Double> games, double statistic) {
        this.name = name;
        this.games = games;
        this.statistic = statistic;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setGames(HashMap<String, Double> games) {
        this.games = games;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getGames() {
        return games;
    }

    public void setStatistic(double statistic) {
        this.statistic = statistic;
    }

    public double getStatistic() {
        return statistic;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nUser name: " + name + "\tUser games: " + games + "\tGeneral statistics: " + statistic;
    }

 public static void statisticMenu(LinkedList<Player> players) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Player player;
        boolean exit = false;
        int enter = 0;
        String[] games  = {"WarFace", "DOTA", "World of Warcraft", "Quake III", "Diablo III"};
        ArrayList<Player> statList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (exit != true) {
            System.out.printf("\n1: ОБЩИЙ РЕЙТИНГ\n2: ПОИСК ПО ИГРОКУ\n3: ПОИСК ПО ИГРЕ\n4: НАЗАД\n");
            switch (enter = scanner.nextInt()) {
                case 1:
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.printf("\nВведите ник игрока:\n");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.printf("\nВыберите игру:\n");
                    while (exit != true) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
                            System.out.printf("\n[" + (i + 1) + "] " + games[i]);
                        }
                        System.out.printf("\n[6] НАЗАД\n");

                        int num = scanner.nextInt();
                        if (num == 6) {
                            exit = true;
                        } else if (num < 1 || num > 6) {
                            System.out.printf("\nНекорректный ввод!!! Выберите игру или выйдите в ГЛАВНОЕ МЕНЮ!\n");
                        } else {
                            System.out.printf("\n\t\tСТАТИСТИКА " + games[num - 1].toUpperCase());
                            for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
//                        String list = players.get(i).toString();
                                player = players.get(i);
                                if (player.getGames().containsKey(games[num - 1])) {
                                    statList.add(player);
                                }
                                else if (i == (players.size() - 1) && statList.size() == 0) {
                                    System.out.printf("\nИгроков играющих в эту игру пока НЕТ");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                       //СОРТИРОВКА ДОЛЖНА БЫТЬ ЗДЕСЬ!!!
                        System.out.printf("\n array " + statList.toString());
                        statList.clear();
                    }
                    exit = false;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    exit = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.printf("\nНекорректный ввод!!! Выберите пункт (1-4)\n");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь stream API.
Если я правильно понял, что конкретно вам нужно, то выглядит примерно так:

```
       List<Player> list = new LinkedList<>();

       String NAME = "GAME_NAME";
    
       Comparator<Player> comparator = (o1, o2) -> Double.compare(o2.getGames().get(NAME),o1.getGames().get(NAME));

       list.stream().filter(el->el.getGames().containsKey(NAME)).sorted(comparator).forEach(System.out::println);
```

list - это список всех игроков, NAME - название игры.

Вы преобразуете свой список в стрим, потом фильтруете и берете только тех игроков, у которых в hashmap имеется данная игра, потом сортируете ее используя компаратор (в компараторе прописана логика сортировки по убыванию). Потом каждый результат выводите на экран. toString у вас в классе Player переопределен, так что должны вывестись. Если я что-то не правильно понял в вашей задаче - сообщите, подправим.

Comment: Проверка `map.containsKey` не гарантирует, что `map.get(NAME)` не вернёт `null`.

Comment: не не гарантирует, чисто отфильтровка

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно просто отсортировать список игроков по статистике в некоторой игре, можно использовать следующий компаратор:

```java
public static void sortPlayersByGame(List<Player> players, String game) {
    players.sort(Comparator.comparing(
        p -> p.getGames().getOrDefault(game, -1d), Comparator.reverseOrder()
    ));
}
```

Если же нужно получить отфильтрованный список, из которого будут исключены игроки, не имеющие статистики по данной игре, можно воспользоваться Stream API:

```java
public static List<Player> sortFilteredPlayersByGame(List<Player> players, String game) {
    return players.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getGames().get(game) != null) // оставить нужных игроков
            .sorted(Comparator.<Player>                  // отсортировать
                comparingDouble(p -> p.getGames().get(game))
                .reversed()                              // по убыванию статы
                .thenComparing(Player::getName)          // и имена по алфавиту
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());               // вернуть новый список
}
```

---

Общее замечание: при определении переменных `games`, `statList` следует использовать интерфейсы коллекций `Map`, `List` вместо конкретных реализаций `HashMap`, `ArrayList`, чтобы убрать ненужную зависимость от типа конкретной реализации, что к примеру упростит тестирование:

```java
List<Player> players = Arrays.asList(
        new Player("John", Map.of("Tetris", 23d, "Counter Strike", 52d, "Quake", 14d), 22d),
        new Player("Jack", Map.of("Quake", 48d, "Half Life", 77d, "Doom", 39d), 12d),
        new Player("Jeff", Map.of("Quake", 19d, "Mario", 37d, "Tetris", 71d), 17d),
        new Player("Alan", Map.of("Doom", 39d, "Mario", 17d, "Tetris", 23d), 17d)
);

System.out.println(players);

sortPlayersByGame(players, "Tetris");
System.out.println(players);

System.out.println(sortFilteredPlayersByGame(players, "Doom"));
```

Результаты:

```
// несортированный список
[Player(name=John, games={Quake=14.0, Counter Strike=52.0, Tetris=23.0}, statistics=22.0), Player(name=Jack, games={Doom=39.0, Quake=48.0, Half Life=77.0}, statistics=12.0), Player(name=Jeff, games={Quake=19.0, Mario=37.0, Tetris=71.0}, statistics=17.0), Player(name=Alan, games={Doom=39.0, Mario=17.0, Tetris=23.0}, statistics=17.0)]

// сортированный по тетрису
[Player(name=Jeff, games={Quake=19.0, Mario=37.0, Tetris=71.0}, statistics=17.0), Player(name=John, games={Quake=14.0, Counter Strike=52.0, Tetris=23.0}, statistics=22.0), Player(name=Alan, games={Doom=39.0, Mario=17.0, Tetris=23.0}, statistics=17.0), Player(name=Jack, games={Doom=39.0, Quake=48.0, Half Life=77.0}, statistics=12.0)]

// фильтрованный и сортированный по думу
[Player(name=Alan, games={Doom=39.0, Mario=17.0, Tetris=23.0}, statistics=17.0), Player(name=Jack, games={Doom=39.0, Quake=48.0, Half Life=77.0}, statistics=12.0)]
```